# Problem while exporting .svg file in blender

Tags: import, svg

When attempting to export an SVG out of blender, I get this error:

[image: Report: Error]

Comment: This looks like a bug in the addon...

Answer (score 1):

The line that says "DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" gives a clue. You can find it documented at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/python.html#mixed-python-libraries-dll-s

A simple fix is to delete or rename "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79" and restart Blender. Then you will need to reinstall or re-enable all your addons.